# About JPA Validation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In My project I am using JPA Validation for my Entities.. I am using two entiy classes say 
(1)InstrumentConfiguration and 
(2)GenericEntity.

In my case 
InstrumentConfiguration extends GenericEntity

There is a field say datemodified in Generic class.. I want to provide the validation to it in extended child class i.e. InstrumentConfiguration.. I want to provide validation using XML file. how should I do it??

Comment: please help me out friends...! I literally got stucked with it..!